# User not found, or token is not authorized in R

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Getting likes from facebook using following command

```
x <- getLikes(XXX, token=token)
```

XXX is the user ID of facebook account of person and token is created by Graph API Explorer.

Using this command, I find like activity of user and user's friend account. Out of 10 friends, I got the following Error for some users

```
likes <- getLikes(XXX, token=token)
Error in getLikes(XXX, token = token) : 
  User not found, or token is not authorized.
```

I create new token also but still I get same Error.
Please tell me what should I do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

While authorizing a user are you enabling extended permissions as true?

If not, then you have to enable extended permissions as follows

```
 fbOAuth(app_id="Your_app_id",app_secret="your_app_secret",extended_permissions=TRUE)
```

Once you do this the getLikes function should work properly for all users

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working for you because facebook has stopped the service. Unless the user that you are requesting details from authorizes your application, you wont be getting the data